# how to join on many-to-many relations using querybuilder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to rebuild it in Symfony2 on a many-to-many relationship between users and accounts with query builder but I am failing. this is the DQL

```
return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
->leftJoin('\FEB\UserBundle\Entity\Userr', 'u')
->where('a.id = :id')
->setParameter('id', $options['pepe']);
```

This is the entities:

user.php

```
namespace FEB\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="feb_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // tu propia lógica
}
}
```

Account.php

```
namespace FEB\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Account
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FEB\UserBundle\Entity\AccountRepository")
*/
class Account
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * Many-To-Many, Unidirectional
    *
    * @var ArrayCollection $idusr
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\FEB\UserBundle\Entity\User")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="accounts_users",
    *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="usr_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    * )
    */
    private $idusr;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->idusr = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

/**
 * Set idusr
 *
 * @param string $idusr
 * @return Account
 */
public function setIdusr($idusr)
{
    $this->idusr = $idusr;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idusr
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getIdusr()
{
    return $this->idusr;
}
```

When I execute the DQL I got all the records of "account" table and not the join:

The SQL statement I want to run would be this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account a
LEFT JOIN accounts_users au ON ( au.usr_id = a.id ) 
WHERE au.usr_id = 1
```

How can I fix it?

Edit 1:

The idea is retrieve the result to populate a drop-down in account form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('titulo')
            ->add('tweet', 'textarea')
            ->add('photo', 'file', array('required' => false))              
            ->add('tags', 'entity', array(
                                            'class' =>    'FEBTagsBundle:tag',
                                            'property' => 'tag',
                                            'empty_value' => 'Selecciona tags',
                                            'multiple' => true))
            ->add('idaccount', 'entity', array(
                                            'class' =>    'FEBUserBundle:Account',
                                            'property' => 'username',
                                            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er ) use ($options) {
                                                return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                                                          ->leftJoin('\FEB\UserBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
                                                          ->where('a.id = :id')
                                                          ->setParameter('id', $options['pepe']);
                                                          //->andWhere('w.visible = 1')
                                                          //->andWhere('w.booked = 0');
                                            ;},
                                            'empty_value' => 'Selecciona account',
                                            'multiple' => false))                                               
                                            ;               
}
```

EDIT2: More info.
The goal is:
From the id of the "feb_user" table, I get the username of the "Account" table. The table feb_user and Account tables are related through the "accounts_users" table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can just query the user like:

```
$Account = $er->find(<<some_id>>);
```

Now you can fetch the account and can access the User entity:

```
$User = $Account->getIduser();
```

Comment: You're right, it's another way. The goal is get that result to populate a drop-down in account form. Edit in my post.

Comment: The goal is:
From the id of the "feb_user" table, I get the username of the "Account" table. The table feb_user and Account tables are related through the "accounts_users" table.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution!
My mistake was in the way I created the DQL. In the leftjoin sentence I referred to the entity, andthe correct way is making reference to the variable that linked the two entities. Would be as follows:

```
->add('idaccount', 'entity', array(
            'class' =>    'FEBUserBundle:Account',
            'property' => 'username',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er ) use ($options) {
                      return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                          ->leftJoin('a.idusr', 'u')
                          ->where('u.id = :id')
                          ->setParameter('id', $options['pepe']);
    },
            'empty_value' => 'Selecciona account',
            'multiple' => false));
```

Thanks to all!!!!